# Random generator producing same numbers by function signature

Tags: python, random, random-seed

I have a function that produces 10 random numbers as follows:

```
import random

def number_generate():
    numbers=[]
    while len(numbers)<10:
        a=int(random.random()*10)
        numbers.append(a)
    return numbers

for i in range(1000000):
    if i%100000==0:
        print(number_generate())
```

It was working fine until I moved the initial list as an input of the function like this:

```
import random

def number_generate(numbers=[]):
    
    while len(numbers)<10:
        a=int(random.random()*10)
        numbers.append(a)
    return numbers

for i in range(1000000):
    if i%100000==0:
        print(number_generate())
```

Now all the produced numbers are the same. What is the difference between these 2 code blocks? Can someone explain this phenomenon?

Comment: `number_generate` remembers what `numbers` was from the previous call.

Comment: add numbers.clear() first line after def

Comment: Python’s default arguments are evaluated only once when the function is defined, not each time the function is called. This means that if a mutable default argument is used and is mutated, it is mutated for all future calls to the function as well. This leads to buggy behaviour as the programmer expects the default value of that argument in each function call.